# Create if non exist directories with year name and subdirectories having month and day date

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am moving logs from a server daily at midnight to a remote server. on the remote server i have to store these logs in relevant folders. means yesterday's logs should be in folder hierarchy like 2021->04->05

my script shall create any none-exist folder/sub folder, I wrote the below script but it create only the main folder (2021) and nothing for its child folder. I believe i have something wrong on the script

```
YEAR="$(date +"%Y")"
MONTH="$(date +"%m")"
DAY="$(date +"%d")"

if [ ! -d "$YEAR" ]; then
 
 mkdir $YEAR
   cd $YEAR
 if [ ! -d "$MONTH" ]; then
      mkdir $MONTH
      cd $MONTH
  if [ ! -d "$DAY" ]; then
        mkdir $DAY
  fi
   fi
fi
```

Comment: Just do mkdir -p 2021/04/05 This will take care of parent and child directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to indent your code consistently. It makes it easier to spot errors.

Your `if` statements do nothing when a test fails. You need to add code to handle the `else` cases:

```
if [ ! -d "$YEAR" ]; then
    mkdir $YEAR
    cd $YEAR
    if [ ! -d "$MONTH" ]; then
        mkdir $MONTH
        cd $MONTH
        if [ ! -d "$DAY" ]; then
            mkdir $DAY
        else
            : # do this if DAY directory exists
        fi
    else
        : # do this if MONTH directory exists
    fi
else
    : # do this if YEAR directory exists
fi
```

Alternatively, in this case it is cleaner to unroll into separate tests:

```
if [ ! -d "$YEAR" ]; then
    mkdir $YEAR
fi
cd $YEAR
if [ ! -d "$MONTH" ]; then
    mkdir $MONTH
fi
cd $MONTH
if [ ! -d "$DAY" ]; then
    mkdir $DAY
fi
cd ../..
```

However, it is even simpler to just let `mkdir` do the work for you with the `-p` option which creates any directories that are needed:

```
mkdir -p "$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY"

# or: mkdir -p "$(date +%Y/%m/%d)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Raman's comment above:

```
mkdir -p $(date '+%Y/%m/%d')
```

The beauty of this is that the `-p` not only creates parent directories as required, but also doesn't fail if a directory already exists.